Kubuntu 24.04, black screen after login, with only a mouse cursor
As far as I can tell, the only system-level thing I did was update the KDE platform via Discover. I noticed that Street Fighter 6, via Proton, was running pretty much locked at 50 FPS no matter what settings I put it on, and if you know anything about fighting games, that's 10 FPS too low. I booted up another game, Divinity: Original Sin II, to see if that was desktop-wide, even though my display refresh rate was set to 144 Hz, because I had noticed my desktop feeling a little sluggish but couldn't put a finger on it. Before D:OS2 could boot, the computer completely locked up, so I hard power cycled. On reboot, I can get to a login screen, but once I enter my credentials, I get a black screen and a mouse cursor with no indication of any kind of error on boot. Recovery mode sees the same thing.
If I leave it on the black screen post-login long enough, it gives me an error box saying startplasma-x11 closed unexpectedly. There's developer information, but I don't know how to get it from that error box to this site gracefully.
https://imgur.com/a/H8uwAlH
I tried "kstart5 plasmashell" from my Ctrl+Alt+F4 shell, and I get the following output.

qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load
the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found. This
application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be
initialized.  Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl,
offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl,
wayland-xcomposite-glx, xcb.
Aborted (core dumped)

I'm not really sure how to reinstall the application. I ran a sudo apt update/upgrade, and I'm up to date. I've tried reinstalling two different packages that might be my xcb, but nothing is changed. Any ideas how to go about troubleshooting from here? I'm on AMD and haven't done anything too crazy with my setup, as far as I know.

I'd guess your gpu driver isn't loading correctly, but it's also possible the kde environment is damaged.  You can probably go to a text console with alt-F2 or something and log in and try to repair it.

Yes, I can get to a terminal with Ctrl+Alt+F4, but I don't know what to do once I'm in there.  I can run apt updates and verify that I have access to my file system, but I don't know how to run any sort of repairs from here.

You should check on (or change?) your video driver, make sure it works.  You didn't say what video card you have, so I can't guess the best way to do this.  Also, checking to see if you can find gdm logs and maybe there is a useful error why it didn't start.

I've got an AMD 6800 XT running mesa drivers.  So try the old apt install --reinstall ?  As for logs, I believe Kubuntu uses ssdm and not gdm, but I'm not an expert here.  I only came across some of this stuff while troubleshooting.

I'm thinking the kernel drivers are damaged, so reinstalling / rebuilding might help, or might expose the real error.  Making sure parts of the desktop are not uninstalled might also help.

So to be clear, you're saying to run a reinstall on mesa?  Which parts might be the kernel drivers, and if it's not running apt reinstall on mesa, how would I reinstall them?

No, reinstall on the kernel driver module for the video card.  apt install --reinstall might work if you know what package the driver is in.  Or, assuming dkms, there's a dkms command to rebuild drivers for specific kernels.  Or look in /var/crash and see if there's a log of an old crashed build.
